# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' in MySQL despite working for other tables

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-workbench, primary-key

Just trying to insert columns and I'm getting the titled error no matter what ID number it is:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testdatabase;
CREATE DATABASE testdatabase CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE testdatabase;

CREATE TABLE table1(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 TEXT,
    col3 TEXT,
    col4 TEXT,
    col5 TEXT,
    col6 TEXT,
    col7 TEXT,
    col8 TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );

CREATE TABLE table2(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 TEXT,
    col3 TEXT,
    col4 TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );

CREATE TABLE table3(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 TEXT,
    col3 TEXT,
    col4 TEXT,
    col5 TEXT,
    col6 TEXT,
    col7 TEXT,
    col8 TEXT,
    col9 TEXT,
    col10 TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );

INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (null, 'one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (null, 'eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen','twenty');
```

When inserting into tables table1 and table2 in the exact same way, everything is fine and it auto-increments ID numbers just fine. It's just table3 that is proving difficult. The first insert runs fine, but any inserts after just refuse to work. I drop the entire database every time I test this and still nothing. I tried running this in SQLFiddle and it worked just fine, but when using SQLWorkbench, or even using Python to insert rows, I get this error. I've been at it for hours with no luck, everywhere online isn't giving any working solutions. This makes no sense to me. This should be working, no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error - is that all the code you have or are there some triggers that might write to table 3.

Comment: No triggers. What you see is all there is. That's why I'm totally baffled. I knew it made no sense. Thanks for confirming I'm not going insane.